# VBA Lotus Notes - Pop Open New Email Window

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes, email

I'm tasked with a very simple objective. Open a new email window in lotus notes using VBA, but please keep reading the fully understand my issue. Currently, I have developed vba code that creates a new email in lotus notes and fills it with all sorts of information, such as the recipient, subject, body and attachments; and then finally sends the email to the recipient. It all works flawlessly. The only problem is that it does all of this behind the scenes, and if it wasn't for checking with the recipient I would have no idea the email sent. To get around this I want the vba code to psychically pop open a new email window, with all of the same information, but instead force me to manually send the email (by hitting the send button). This way I know the email will have been sent, and also so I can add in extra information if needed.

I've looked at more threads than I can count and all seem to address a slightly different issue than mine. Any suggestions or hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Thanks for the suggestions. Heres my code:

```
Sub Prepare_email()

Dim Maildb As Object
Dim MailDoc As Object
Dim Body As Object
Dim Session As Object
Dim Subject As String

'Start a session to notes
Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")

'This line prompts for password of current ID noted in Notes.INI
Call Session.Initialize

'Open the mail database in notes
Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then

Else
    Call Maildb.Open
End If

'Create the mail document
Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo")


'Set the recipient, calls a GetPrimary Email function
Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", GetPrimaryEmail)

'Set subject, calls subject function
Subject = getCompanyName
Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", Subject)

'Create and set the Body content
Set Body = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Body")
Call Body.APPENDTEXT("BODY Content")

'Example to save the message 
MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True

'Send the document
Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("PostedDate", Now())
Call MailDoc.SEND(False)

'Clean Up
Set Maildb = Nothing
Set MailDoc = Nothing
Set Body = Nothing
Set Session = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: You should show your code so people don't have to guess what you've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "behind the scenes", I presume you mean that you are using the Notes "back-end classes". If you want to actually open a window in the client, you have to use the "front-end" classes.

An important difference to understand is that the "front-end" classes are exposed as OLE objects (Notes.NotesUIWorkspace), and the "back-end" classes are exposed both as OLE (Notes.NotesSession) and COM (Lotus.NotesSession) objects. Note the different prefixes: 'Notes' for OLE classes, 'Lotus' for COM classes.

The NotesUIWorspace class and the other front-end classes that you can drive through it are all about automating the actual operation of the Notes client. You can find documentation for the NotesUIWorkspace class [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESUIWORKSPACE_CLASS.html?lang=en).  When you use OLE classes, the Notes client starts automatically unless it is already running. When you use the COM classes, the Notes client does not need to be running and does not start automatically.

Comment: Awesome. Thank! Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

The first step involves saving your document instead of calling `Send`, i.e. call `Call doc.Save( True, True )` if `doc` is your `NotesDocument` class.

The second step is showing the document by using `CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace").EDITDOCUMENT True, doc`

As a side note: Showing your code would actually help answering the question!